# Git cloned from svn repository doesn't recognize remote

Tags: git, git-svn

Today I got our svn repository cloned into git. I had some uncommitted work though, so I `svn commit` them and then went to pull them into the git repository.

The problem is, git seems to be somehow confused about the svn repository.

First of all, `git remote` shows nothing! However, if I write `git pull <tab>`, it auto-completes `svn-remote.svn`. Trying that results in

```
fatal: 'svn-remote.svn' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I went to look inside git's own files. Here is the config file:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = svn+ssh://myname@repository_address
        fetch = libskin/dev:refs/remotes/trunk
        branches = libskin/branch/*:refs/remotes/*
```

So the remote *is* actually there (although oddly enough the branches are not). So I went about trying `git pull svn` and `git pull trunk` and other things, and they all failed with the same message.

I even tried adding a branch manually in the config file:

```
[branch "master"]
        remote = svn
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

but the problem persists.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use both Git and Subversion, the command you use is [git-svn](http://man.github.com/git/git-svn.html)

```
git svn fetch
git svn rebase
```

you cannot get the new svn committed with normal git command. You may read more [tutorial here](http://andy.delcambre.com/2008/03/04/git-svn-workflow.html).

Answer (score 0):

To use both Git and Subversion just install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into your repository.
It keeps SVN and Git repositories in sync automatically on the server. So you may use any SVN or Git client to work with the repository. Compared to git-svn it preserves SVN concepts like ignores, EOLs, tags and so on much better (translating them to .gitignore, .gitattributes, Git tags and so on).

If you need a client-only solution, I would recommend you to use [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html). It preserves these SVN concepts better than git-svn too.
.